# Найти речевую ошибку

Tags: грамотная-речь

Став чемпионом Европы, фигурист сделал своеобразный спортивный подвиг.
Я долго греб веслами, отчего на ладонях рук образовались мозоли.
Где в этих предложениях речевая ошибка ?

Comment: Предложите свой вариант решения, а сообщество подправит, если будут ошибки. Выполнять за других домашние задания здесь не принято.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что не выполняю чужих домашних заданий

Comment: Согласен с mueller. Закрывал бы по сигналу ТРЕВОГА, хотя и в подобных случаях ответы энтузиастами даются.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Став чемпионом Европы, фигурист **сделал** своеобразный спортивный
>   подвиг.

Подвиг можно ***совершить***, но не ***сделать***.

> Я долго греб веслами, отчего на ладонях **рук** образовались мозоли.

***"Рук"*** в этом предложении -- лишнее слово. Ладоней ног не бывает. ЛАДОНЬ -- внутренняя сторона кисти ***руки***.